# Dropdown list is hiding under other input fields when using react-bootstrap-typeahead in the MS powerapps control

Tags: css, powerapps, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I used react-bootstrap-typeahead to create a Microsoft powerapps control and add the control to one of the field from Account object in the Dynamic 365 Sales Hub.But when I did the typeahead, the dropdown list is hiding under other Account fields, it is not showing on top of them. I tried to add z-index=1000 to the style but it didn't help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @Ying Luan, welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to post any relevant code samples (JS, CSS, HTML) to help others better understand and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi @teylyn, Could you explian what do you mean by changing the visibility of the control? where can I change that? Thanks.